# Detecting ultrasonic by microphone and MCU

Tags: microcontroller, communication, ultrasound, detector

I design data-over-audio transmission to MCU. To do it i need ultrasonic detector with specific frequency, for example 50kHz.

Seems, that electret microphone+low-pass filter+envelope detector will solve problem

**Microphone**
[image: microphone]
**Low-pass filter**
[image]
**Envelope detector**
[image]

How to calculate resistors and capacitors for this scheme?

Also i have idea to use ready-made solution HC-SR04, but don't know, is it ok
[image: ultrasonic delector]

Comment: If your signal is 50 KHz, your receiver should have a bandpass filter tuned to 50 KHz.  To be useful, a low-pass filter would need a cutoff frequency of 60 KHz or so and would pass lots of unwanted noise below your desired frequency.

Comment: @PeterBennet Need i add high pass filter? Or use LC circuit instead of high and low pass filters?

Comment: Your concept fails to recover any audio. Do some more re-search.

Comment: With a suitable circuit you might get 100 baud with this card for a few meters.  While IRDA2 can do a  1MBd.+

Comment: You actually need to choose a microphone that will respond to frequencies as high as 50 kHz. Find one first then come back.

Comment: @Andyaka i bought this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone

Comment: What frequency response does it have? Linking to wiki is meaningless. Try again.

Comment: @Andyaka i don't tested it, but same mic uses in smartphones. I need to try. Please help me with calculations

Comment: Choose a microphone that will work adequately at 50 kHz I said. Smartphone microphones might only be guaranteed to possibly 15 kHz.